# Limits of integration when applying stochastic Fubini theorem to Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I'm looking at the solution below from Quantuple, it's a nice, succinct solution but I'm confused about how the limits of the integrals in the second line come from. Could someone please elaborate on that part?

[Integral of Brownian Motion w.r.t Time](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/integral-of-brownian-motion-w-r-t-time)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equality that you are asking about is

$$
\int_0^t \int_0^s \mathrm{d}W_u \mathrm{d}s = \int_0^t \int_u^t \mathrm{d}s \mathrm{d}W_u.
$$

When applying Fubini, you need to make sure that the domain that you are integrating over doesn't change. On the left-hand side, both $s$ takes values in $[0, t]$ and for any given $s$, $u \in [0, s]$. See the below plot.

[image]

Now when you reverse the order of integration, you let $u$ go from $[0, t]$. To integrate over the same area, for any given $u$, you need to let $s \in [u, t]$. See the second plot, which is essentially just the first one mirrored along the diagonal.

[image]