# How to numerically simulate exponential stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

For example given an integral

$$
\int^t_0 \exp(aW(t'))\,dt', t\in\mathbb R_+
$$
where $W(t')$ is a standard Wiener process.

I've been very confused about stochastic integrals like $\int^t_0 W(t')\,dt'$, for example here [Integral of Brownian motion w.r.t. time](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/integral-of-brownian-motion-w-r-t-time)

My question is how to numerically simulate this integral (i.e. simulate trajectories with evolution of time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

making use of this formula :

$$ y(t_{k+1}) = y({t_k}) + \int^{t_{k+1}}_{t_k} y(t) dt $$

Let's define $F$ as:
$$
F(t)=\int^t_0 \exp(aW(t'))\,dt', \forall t\in\mathbb R_+\\
dF(t)=\exp(aW(t))dt
$$

1. Choose a small $\Delta t$.
2. Simulate $\Delta W\sim \mathcal N(0,\Delta t)$
3. Calculate $W(t+\Delta t)=W(t) + \Delta W$
4. Calculate $F(t+\Delta t)=F(t)+ \exp(aW(t))\Delta t $
5. Repeat 2, 3 and 4 as many times as you want.

Comment: Hi, I think your second step should read "2. Simulate $\Delta W\sim N(0,\sqrt{\Delta t})$"

Comment: That is the variance

Answer (score 2):

@ThomasG's solution is implemented in python (give or take some care with the zero index) as:

```
import numpy as np

dt = 1e-2; j = 10; a = 1

dW = np.random.randn(j+1); dW[0] = 0
W = np.cumsum(dW)
F = np.cumsum(np.exp(a * W) * dt)
```

Comment: don't you think that if you generate dW like that, meaning on intervals of length 0.1, the normal vector should be generated by $ \mathcal N(0, 0.1)$ ?
for that reason, I'd have written : np.cumsum(np.exp(a * W * \sqrt dt ) * dt )

Comment: Yes in hindsight seem like I made an error here that you describe