# change of measure expectation

Tags: girsanov, stochastic, expected-value

[image]

How to find expectation of this stochastic process? Also, to show that the expectation of a stochastic process expression [Xt - St] in one measure is equal to expectation of another expression (of the mentioned stochastic process) in another measure?

Given:
$S_t=S_0e^{\sigma W_t+(r-\sigma^2/2)t}$

$dS_t = rS_tdt + \sigma S_tdW_t$

Comment: What is your dynamic of $S_t$?

Comment: $S_t=S_0e^{\sigma W_t+(r-\sigma^2/2)t}$     It took me forever to type this up using latex.

Comment: Hint: take the log of $S_t$, write out the integral in the exponent and you'll have one non-random term and one term which is $\sigma \int_0^t W_u \mathrm{d}u$. Then see https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29504. This integral is normally distributed which should help you compute the expectation you are looking for.

Comment: Please show your work. What have you tried, and how far have you gotten? Also, if this is a homework assignment, it should be marked as such.

Answer (score 1):

Your process for $(S_t)$ is a geoemtric Brownian motion and since $S_t=S_0 e^{\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t+\sigma W_t}$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\ln(S_t) &= \ln(S_0)+\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t+\sigma W_t \\
&\sim N\left(\ln(S_0)+\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t,\sigma^2 t\right).
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
X_t &= e^{\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t \ln(S_u)\mathrm{d}u} \\
&= e^{\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t \left(\ln(S_0)+\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)u\right)\mathrm{d}u}\cdot e^{\frac{1}{t}\sigma\int_0^t W_u\mathrm{d}u} \\
&=  S_0\cdot e^{\frac{1}{2}\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t}\cdot e^{\frac{1}{t}\sigma\int_0^t W_u\mathrm{d}u}.
\end{align*}
Fortunately, the time integral of a Brownian motion is well-known to be normally distributed with mean zero and variance $\frac{1}{3}t^3$, see [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/integral-of-brownian-motion-w-r-t-time). Remember that if $Z\sim N(0,1)$, then $\mathbb{E}\left[e^Z\right]=e^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and thus $\mathbb{E}\left[e^{m+s Z}\right]=e^{m+\frac{1}{2}s^2}$. As a consequence, $X_t$ is log-normally distributed with
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X_t] &= S_0\cdot e^{\frac{1}{2}\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t}\cdot \mathbb{E}\left[e^{\frac{1}{t}\sigma\int_0^t W_u\mathrm{d}u}\right] \\
&= S_0\cdot e^{\frac{1}{2}\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t}\cdot \mathbb{E}\left[e^{\frac{1}{t}\sigma \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}t^3}Z} \right] \\
&= S_0\cdot e^{\frac{1}{2}\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t}\cdot \mathbb{E}\left[e^{ \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}t\sigma^2}Z} \right] \\
&= S_0\cdot e^{\frac{1}{2}\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t}\cdot e^{ \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3}\sigma^2t} \\
&= S_0\cdot e^{\frac{1}{2}\left(r-\frac{1}{6}\sigma^2\right)t}.
\end{align*}