# Covariance between integral of brownian motion and brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, itos-lemma, covariance

Let

$$
I = \int_0^1W_tdt,
$$

where $W_t$ is a Brownian motion.
From [Integral of Brownian motion w.r.t. time](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/integral-of-brownian-motion-w-r-t-time?newreg=2b8ba41a6572435ea818f95678e3d1c8) we have that

$$
\mathbb{E}[I]=0,
$$
by Fubini's theorem. And that
$$
\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[I] = \mathbb{E}[I^2] = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^1\int_0^1W_sW_tdsdt\right] = \int_0^1\int_0^1\mathbb{E}[W_sW_t]dsdt = \frac{1}{3}.
$$
Here I do not understand how we are able to bring the expectation into the integral, Ito isometry says that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^tX_sdW_s\right)^2\right] = \int_0^t\mathbb{E}[X_s^2]ds
$$
so I am unsure how it is possible to use this here?

Furthermore, I am required to find
$$
\mathbb{C}\text{ov}[I, W_1],
$$

I know that
$$
\mathbb{C}\text{ov}[I, W_1] = \mathbb{E}[IW_1],
$$
since $\mathbb{E}[I] = \mathbb{E}[W_1] = 0$,
my best guess here is then that
$$
\mathbb{E}[IW_1] = \min\left(\frac{1}{3},1\right) = \frac{1}{3},
$$
however, this is probably wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: you can write $ I =\int_0^1 W_t dt = \int_0^1(1-t)dW_t$. Can you see why this is true and how it helps? For the second part you need the slighlty more general version of Ito isometry. I can make a complete answer but I'll give you some time to think about it if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the **first** question, equality
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]} W_sW_tdsdt\right] = \int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}\mathbb{E}[W_sW_t]dsdt \left(= \int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}\min(s,t)dsdt\right) $$

is due to commuting expectation and integral (not to Ito isometry), which in turn is allowed by [Fubini's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499158/conditions-of-fubinis-theorem) condition being met:

$$ \left(\int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}\mathbb{E}\left[|W_sW_t|  \right] ds dt \right)^2\leq  $$ $$\int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}\mathbb{E}\left[|W_sW_t|  \right]^2 ds dt \leq \int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]} \mathbb{E}\left[W_s^2  \right] \mathbb{E}\left[W_t^2  \right] dsdt $$ $$= \int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}st dsdt = \frac{1}{4}  <\infty  $$

(with first and second inequalities being applications of Jensen and Cauchy-Schwarz inequalities, respectively).

For the **second** question, one way is to use the definition of the *time* integral (Riemann pathwise) and use covariance properties:

$$ {\rm cov} \left(\int_0^1 W_tdt, W_1 \right) = {\rm cov} \left(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} W_{\frac{k}{n}}, W_1\right) $$

$$= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {\rm cov} \left(   W_{\frac{k}{n}}, W_1\right)  = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{k}{n} $$ $$= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(n-1)n}{2n^2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions that you are asking:

1. How to prove $\text{Var}[I] = \frac{1}{3}$? and
2. What is $\text{Cov}[I, W_1]$?

For **Question 1**, you absolutely can use Ito isometry. First, note that we can use integration by parts to obtain the formula:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 W_t dt &= W_1 - \int_0^1tdW_t \\
&= \int_0^1(1-t)dW_t
\end{align}
So we can write $I=\int_0^1(1-t)dW_t$ (switching from Riemann integral to an Ito integral like this is often a useful trick). Now,
\begin{align}
\text{Var}[I] = \text{E}[I^2] &= \text{E}\bigg[\bigg(\int_0^1(1-t)dW_t\bigg)^2\bigg] \\
&= \int_0^1(1-t)^2dt \\
&= \frac{1}{3}
\end{align}
where we use Ito isometry (exactly as you stated) to go from the first to the second line.

For **Question 2**, we use Ito isometry again. But this time the slightly more general form ([see the very last equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry)). So,
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}[W_1, I] = \text{E}[W_1, I] &= \text{E}\bigg[W_1 \int_0^1tdW_t\bigg] \\
&= \text{E}\bigg[\int_0^1dW_t \int_0^1tdW_t\bigg] \\
&= \int_0^1tdt \\
&= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
where we use the general Ito isometry to go from line 2 to line 3.