# what is $\int t dW$ and $\int W dt$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

More explicitly, if $W(t)$ is Brownian motion, what would be
$$f(t) := \int_0^t u dW(u)$$
and $$g(t) := \int_0^t W(u) du$$?

Comment: $f + g = tW$ by application of Ito.

Comment: @FridoRolloos indeed, but i'm interested in $f$ and $g$ separately.

Comment: I do not think there is an explicit expression for the separate terms.

Comment: @FridoRolloos mmm.. is there a criterion on which integrals have or have not explicit expressions?

Comment: it can be closed as i found a previous question : https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/integral-of-brownian-motion-w-r-t-time

Comment: For every $t \geq 0,$ both $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are random variables $N(0,t^3/3).$