# Integral of brownian motion wrt. time over [t;T]

Tags: brownian-motion, itos-lemma, distribution, wienerprocess, stochastic-integral

From the post [Integral of Brownian motion w.r.t. time](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/integral-of-brownian-motion-w-r-t-time) we have an argument for

$$\int_0^t W_sds \sim N\left(0,\frac{1}{3}t^3\right).$$

However, how does this generalise for the interval $[t;T]$? I.e. what is the distribution of

$$\int_t^T W_sds.$$

I would expect it to be
$$\int_t^T W_sds \sim N\left(0,\frac{1}{3}(T-t)^3\right),$$

but I cannot see why.

Answer (score 4):

The last integral is correct as

$$\int_t^T W_s ds = \int_t^T (T-s) dW_s \sim N\left(0, \int_t^T(T-s)^2ds\right) = N\left(0,\frac{1}{3}(T-t)^3\right).$$

Ref. *Arbitrage Theory in Continuos Time (Björk, 4th edition)*

Comment: I'd look it up in Bjork but I don't have that book. Can you explain the first equality ?  I get the rest of it. Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds first equality comes from writing $W$ as $\int dW$ then inverting the order of integration by stochastic Fubini.

Comment: got it now. thanks.

Comment: Does Björk really make the claim $\int_t^TW_s\,ds=\int_t^T(T-s)\,dW_s\,?$ If so, where exactly (I don't have that book) ? For $t>0$ it seems [wrong](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/75919/58786).